# Reverse Proxy for c++

Tags: c++, tcp, udp, connection, reverse-proxy

I have been trying to find a working http reverse proxy or a socks reverse proxy. The goal I am trying to achieve is to effectivly browse the internet on the clients connection, for example "Open up a browser in your server instance and configure your HTTP proxy to port 6000, now you will be effectively browsing the Internet with client's connection." This is a perfect example of this github repositary what can be found here - https://github.com/jafarlihi/revp Sadly  this project doesnt seem to work. So if anyone can recommend me an alternitive that is written in c++, that would be great.

Comment: If you're not planning to write it yourself, why do you care what language it's written in?

Comment: I am planning to learn from it and to modify it.

Comment: So why not learn from the existing project by getting it to work? At the moment you have a question asking for tool recommendations, which isn't on-topic just because you want the source of the tool. At least you might have an on-topic question about _why_ the existing one doesn't work.